# About Solidity Transferfrom and Approve Functions

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, erc20

I actually need a very simple smart contract using the following functions "transferfrom" and "approve".

I just need a smart contract that will be able to request approval to spend a token ( example -- bake ) from a wallet if the user calls the "approve" function.

It will also be able to withdraw the particular token from the user's wallet to the "address to" set by the contract's onwer, if the onwer calls the "transferfrom" function.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a design limitation of the [ERC20](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-20) standard that disallows approval through a contract in between.

The user always needs to invoke the `approve()` function on the token contract directly - not through your contract.